# Angular post sending data to webapi as null

Tags: angularjs, html, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I don't know what i am doing wrong in my code i m trying to send some values to webapi controller it heating breakpoints calling correct method but always i get parameters as null.
I tried with JSONStringfy
set headers and many ways but still all are fails

Here are some code snippets for angular method

```
$http.post('/api/EmployeeData/' + p.EmpNo, JSON.stringify(p))
  .success(function(data) {
    Alert(ok)
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    data;
});
```

other ways

```
$http({
    url: '/api/EmployeeData/' + p.EmpNo,
    data: JSON.stringify(p), //or this as well p,// or {Employee: p},
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    } //or {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
})('/api/EmployeeData/' + p.EmpNo, JSON.stringify(p)).success(function(data) {
    Alert(ok)
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    data;
});
```

Code snippets for for API controller

```
 public HttpResponseMessage PostEmployee([FromBody] Employee employee) {

    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        db.Employees.Add(employee);
        db.SaveChanges();

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, employee);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new {
            id = employee.EmpNo
        }));
        return response;
    } else {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
 }
```

**but still i m getting Employee as null even i changed the type of parameters as well to string **

```
HttpResponseMessage to IHttpActionResult
```

but still the same

I dont knw what wrong i m doing any suggestion will be really appreciable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you watched the network request in your browser to see if it is sending the correct data to the endpoint? If the body is correct in the POST, then the problem is in the API controller.

Comment: Ya i watched but still the same.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your Angular controller code.

Comment: I have tested it is works with chrome and seems not working with IE.

Comment: Is it IE 10 by chance? Your issue seems similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643665/angular-resource-post-produces-an-invalid-json-body-in-internet-explorer-10

Comment: Removed the breeze tag as there is no apparent connection to breezejs in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't 'p' already json? JSON.stringify is not needed:

```
$http.post('/api/EmployeeData/'+ p.EmpNo, p)
```

Also, your PostEmployee method is missing the [HttpPost] attribute.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Ya its json i tried with all the scenarios with json and without json as well... u can see the code i explained about this as well.